# I can´t get all folders from my branch on GIT

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a git project with one branch, I´m trying to clone all files in my local folder, but I can´t get the vendor folder. I would like to know if I can do it in other way to get also vendor class.

I´m running this:
    git clone -b branch_name repo_URL

As I say, I don´t get one folder. What I need to do it to get all files?

PD: I can´t download a ZIP of the project.

Comment: Is a folder, I have 8-9 foldes in my project, one of this is the vendor. The project is in GitLab.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Sorry, this is genuine PHP stuff, your suggestions are leading in the wrong direction. The question was tagged `composer-php`, which is PHP's dependency manager. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: @Sven Sorry, completely missed that, I've deleted my comments to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to find that `vendor` folder in your repository. It would be useless redundancy.

In modern PHP projects, [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) is being used to manage external dependencies. When running `composer update`, it reads a file `composer.json` (which should be present in your repository) to find the most recent versions of the external packages to be used.

This creates a file `composer.lock` (which should also be in your repository) with the exact versions and commits that got downloaded. If at any later time someone (like you now) wants to recreate the contents of the `vendor` folder, they run `composer install`, which will try to get everything that was once downloaded.

So the first step for you is to download Composer, then run `composer install` (depending on your way of downloading, it might also be `php composer.phar install` or something close to that).

Reasons for `composer install` to fail is that dependencies can no longer be downloaded because they were removed from the internet, or that the project is too old and has too old versions of said files so that it does not run with current versions of Composer (although this should be very rare). In any case: If you encounter errors, ask a new question here with all the details, including the full output of the Composer command.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't get the vendor folder is because the vendor folder never went up to the git repository. If you see the **.gitignore** file, you will notice a :

```
/vendor
```

This tells git to ignore that folder and not to send it up to the git repository when you are pushing. There is no way for you to get that folder unless you find the original project before you pushed to the git.

Comment: There is no alternative?

Comment: You have no way of accessing the original project before pushed to git?